Connecting to Heroku Postgres with a different environment variable
The app I'm trying to deploy to Heroku uses an environment variable different from the one Heroku Postgres automatically sets and I'm unable to find a way to change it. That is, my app uses the environment variable CONNECTION_URI instead of DATABASE_URL to connect to Postgres and I cannot find a way to change it on Heroku.
I have searched the settings panel and the Heroku documentation but I could not find any solutions.
